# Run codes for only 60 times each second

Tags: c++

I'm creating a directx application that relies on the system time (because it must be accurate),
and I need to run lines of code for 60 times each second in the background (in a thread created by boost::thread). that's equal to 60 FPS (frame per second), but without depending on the main application frame rate.

```
//.................
void frameThread()
{
    // I want to run codes inside this loop for *exactly* 60 times in a second.
    // In other words, every 16.67 (1000/60) milliseconds
    for(;;)
    {
      DoWork();
      //.........
    }
}
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
   initialize();
   //.....stuffs
   boost::thread framethread(frameThread);
   //......
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Any kind of help would be appreciated :)

Comment: you know, there is a difference between running 60 times a second and running every 1/60th of a second :)

Comment: Should the DoWork() executions be distributed equally within 1 second? Can it be executed 60 times, say within 0.5 seconds, followed by 0.5 seconds of idling?

Comment: it is continuous, but it should run 60 times a second.

Comment: Sounds like you want to enable V-sync, rather than forcing an arbitrary fixed framerate.  See my answer for advice on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since 60 Hz is a common monitor refresh rate, it sounds like you want to enable V-Sync, instead of messing around with timers and sleeps.

You mentioned you're using DirectX - If you're using DirectX 9, specify [D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_ONE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172585(VS.85).aspx) when creating the device, and the application will synchronize to the monitor refresh rate.  Usually this is 60 Hz - but it could also in theory be anything, such as 50Hz, 85Hz or 120Hz.  You get a very nice tear-free display though - if you don't use V-sync, you'll likely get tearing artefacts when scrolling.

This raises the problem: how do you make the game progress at the same speed if the framerate could vary so much?  The answer is simple - use a high resolution timer (like [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(VS.85).aspx) on Windows), and measure the time between each frame.  Then you need to base any motion or movement off this 'delta time' value.  This is a good thing to do anyway, even with a fixed framerate - it prevents your game suddenly running in slow motion if the computer is slow and the player only gets 20fps.

Here's an example of moving an object horizontally at 100 pixels per second, regardless of the framerate:

```
object.x += 100.0f * delta_time; // same speed no matter the framerate
```

This IMO is a much better way of doing this, especially given it's tearing-free, framerate-independent, and synchronises with the user's monitor, not some arbitrary framerate you set yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Can you show me an example usage of QueryPerformanceCounter; the simple ones? I'm new to that API.

Comment: Just google some examples, it's really simple.  QueryPerformanceCounter gives you a high resolution time value, QueryPerformanceFrequency gives you the units per second that QueryPerformanceCounter returns.  So call QueryPerformanceCounter every tick, get the difference between the values, divide by frequency, you have your high-resolution time in seconds as a float.

Answer (score 2):

Get the system time before DoWork(), add to it a 1/60 of a second and store it for later use. After DoWork() (which must run for less than a 1/60 of a second) you have to sleep until the system time is equal to the previously stored time. That should do the trick.

Comment: Although beware that 1/60th of a second may be less than the resolution of the system time. Certainly it's close to it, so you won't get a smooth distribution using system time.

Comment: That's true. You depend entirely on the accuracy of the timer you use to check the time and the timer used for the Sleep() call. On the other hand, slight inaccuracies in a 60FPS loop should not be really noticeable to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Use [waitable timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687008%28VS.85%29.aspx) as a synchronization object.

```
HANDLE hWaitTimer;

void frameThread()
{
    while ( WaitForSingleObject( hWaitTimer, INFINITE ) == WAIT_OBJECT_0 )
    {
      // reactivate timer
      LARGE_INTEGER due_time = {0};
      due_time.LowPart = 10000/60; // in 100 nanosecond intervals
      ::SetWaitableTimer( hWaitTimer,  &due_time, 0, NULL, NULL, FALSE );

      DoWork();
      //.........
    }
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    hWaitTimer = ::CreateWaitableTimer( NULL, FALSE, NULL );
    LARGE_INTEGER due_time = {0};
    due_time.LowPart = 10000/60; // in 100 nanosecond intervals
    ::SetWaitableTimer( hWaitTimer,  &due_time, 0, NULL, NULL, FALSE );

    // create trhead etc.


    // before exit
    CloseHandle( hWaitTimer );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "accurate" ? Windows isn't an RTOS so there is no way you can get real accuracy out of it. You can get pretty close, but you can't guarantee that your thread will be scheduled when you want it at all.

Anyway, I'd go for a waitable timer, a thread pool and RegisterWaitForSingleObject.

Comment: means I need the code to be ran exactly 60 times in a second; not less.

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "exactly" ? What's the required precision ? is code that runs every second plus or minus 10 MS acceptable ? 1 ms ? 100 ms ? Is regularity more important than precision ? Does the interval take the time it takes to run the code into account or not ?

Comment: @djzmo: that's impossible on Windows. Suppose some high-priority entity, like the kernel or a device driver, is running slow and hogging the CPU(s) for 1/30th of a second or longer. Then your program will not run at all in that time, and you may not "catch up" by the end of the second. You need to change your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need high precision, use platform-specific multimedia timer, see timeSetEvent function, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa448195.aspx. Use TIME_PERIODIC with TIME_CALLBACK_FUNCTION flags, uResolution=0. In any case DirectX is not portable.

I don't think that you can get required precision using cross-platform Boost thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% that you will not run longer that 1/60s then solution would be to use [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) and separate timer that ticks every 1/60s.

In timer thread you semaphore.V() and in your worker thread you semaphore.P().

Windows has [native semaphores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682438(VS.85).aspx).

If your worker thread can take longer than 1/60 then you should compensate for that via some kind of "worker_lock" instance variable. Never lock in timer thread, it must be as fast as possible. Also raise the priority of timer receiving thread.